# Adjusting the size of the coverage window?

Tags: sonarqube

In my sonarqube (3.6.2)  instance, if I click on my project's (Java, built with Maven, evaluated with JaCoCo) coverage number, I am taken to a page which contains 3 windows containing module, package, and class, respectively.

These windows are short (about 5 lines vertically) and they are stacked horizontally, requiring that I scroll left and right to see them.

I've been unable to find any obvious way to increase the window sizes or to adjust their placement on the page.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tune this behaviour. Are you using a low screen resolution ? If this is not the case could attach a screenshot ?

Comment: I have insufficient reputation points for SOF to allow me to post a screenshot. Let me know if there is some other way to get it to you.

Comment: What's your screen resolution ?

Comment: Screen resolution is 1920x1280 (running Firefox 22 on Ubuntu, however others with Macs in my office see the same thing).

Comment: In that case, send me a private email to $my-first-name.$my-last-name@gmail.com with the screenshot. thanks

Comment: Sent. Please let me know if it fails to arrive.

Comment: I do confirm the limitation when having some long package names (as this is your case) and I've created a JIRA ticket to solve it : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4607